# How to show the associativity in this group?

Tags: group-theory, associativity

The group law is given by $a \oplus b = \frac{a+b}{1+a\,b}$ for $a,b \in G = (-1,1)$

For associativity I guess I have to show $(a \oplus b) \oplus c = a \oplus (b \oplus c)$, hence:

$$\begin{equation}\frac{\frac{a+b}{1+a\,b}+c}{1+\frac{a+b}{1+a\,b}\,c}= \frac{\frac{c+b}{1+c\,b}+a}{1+\frac{c+b}{1+c\,b}\,a}\end{equation}$$

but I got a hard time doing so. Is this actually the task?

Comment: It's easier to show if you know the angle formula for $\arctan$

Comment: Just do it, as they say. What on earth is difficult about the calculation?

Comment: @Jakobian Your remark is interesting but not in the spirit of the question, which is a routine verification...

Comment: Sorry guys, needed to be carried :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. And in the expression$$\frac{\frac{a+b}{1+ab}+c}{1+\frac{a+b}{1+ab}c},$$you multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $1+ab$, then you will get$$\frac{a+b+c+abc}{1+ab+ac+bc}.$$Now, do a similar thing to the RHS.

Comment: Amazing, dividing by $1+b\,c$ spits out the sought result already. Gotta give you the tick for pure elegancy.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\begin{align}
(a\oplus b)\oplus c&=\left(\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right)\oplus c\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right)+c}{1+\left(\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right)c}\\
&=\frac{(a+b)+c(1+ab)}{(1+ab)+(a+b)c}\\
&=\frac{(a+b)+c+abc}{1+ab+ac+bc}\\
&=\frac{a(1+bc)+(b+c)}{(1+bc)+(b+c)a}\\
&=\frac{a+\left(\frac{b+c}{1+bc}\right)}{1+a\left(\frac{b+c}{1+bc}\right)}\\
&=a\oplus\left(\frac{b+c}{1+bc}\right)\\
&=a\oplus(b\oplus c).
\end{align}$$

But there's more: since $a,b\in (-1,1)$, we have

$$-1<a\oplus b=\frac{a+b}{1+ab}<1$$

by looking at extreme cases, so $a\oplus b\in(-1,1)$.